# ldap search for unique members returning all uniqueMembers

Tags: php, ldap, phpldapadmin

I have a group that has a large number of uniqueMembers, i am trying to search that group for a specific member but it returns all members which results in a long wait for the search to finish.

This is my search right now

```
$usr = ldap_search($connection, "cn=grp1,cn=customers,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=com", "(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=uid=USER1,cn=users,dc=company,dc=com))");
```

This search returns all uniqueMembers from that group but i dont understand why its not filtering for the uniqueMember USER1 ?
I have tried changing the search filters but using just uniqueMember=USER1 or uniqueMember=uid=USER1 doesnt return anything.

Comment: You are searching for `(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)`. This will never give you a single group member, but always the complete group. The group has a multi-valued `uniqueMember` attribute listing all its members, including `uid=USER1,cn=users,dc=company,dc=com`, so the second filter predicate matches the group, but otherwise does nothing. Turn the search around. Filter for the object class that the group *contains*, look at their attributes, and then filter for the "member of" attribute.

Comment: Im not sure i follow properly. 
First part makes sense, i should have mentioned i searched with objectClass to.
The group has an objectClass of GroupOfUniqueNames (i only added this recently when trying to resolve this search issue) The filtering for the member of bit has me confused could you elaborate further please?

Comment: The group is the group. It is *one* object. You can't filter it down "more". Groups are not containers (!) - they are just a singular objects with a list of DNs in one of their attributes. If you want to retrieve a particular member of the group, you need to search for the actual member objects (e.g. `(objectClass=person)`, or whatever it is), and filter *them* down to those that are member of that particular group. There will be some sort of `memberOf` attribute that contains the group DN.

Comment: ahh ok i follow you, thanks for explaining it for me.

Comment: Since groups are not containers, you can't use them as the search base. You won't get any results if you do that. Either use `dc=company,dc=com` as the search base, or something more specific than that, but make sure that all the member objects you are interested in have your search base in their respective DNs.

Comment: As @Tomalak said, you can not expect to retrieve a user searching for a group.

The desire search for a group and then obtain a user object, then it will take two search requests.

First one for to get the user DN:

    ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.example.com:636 -x -D "cn=admin" -W -b "cn=grp1,cn=customers,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=com" -s sub -a always -z 1000 "(uniqueMember=uid=USER1,cn=users,dc=company,dc=com)"

From this you should get the DN for the user Entry uid=USER1,cn=users,dc=company,dc=com

But if you know the user entry already why are you searching?

Comment: makes sense now. I am trying to see if the user is in the group. It seems i dont have this member object that shows which group they are in. When its two searches the first one takes to long as the groups are massive and as we have established i cant filter the group so it returns all of the group